# Laravel 10 добавление к существующим данным JSON записи в таблице PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, postgresql

В общем задача:
есть большой файл с данными, который хочу положить в JSON массив таблицы PostgreSQL.
Но не могу заставить добавлять туда данные, при обновлении происходит их затирание:

```php
$ItemDoc= ItemDoc::findOrFail($this->item_doc_id);
$ItemDoc->update(['file_dump'=>$row]);
```

Можно прочитать, изменить и обновить, но это большая нагрузка, которая недопустима и скорей всего повесит процесс.

Comment: Зачем большие файлы хранить в базе?

Comment: записывать по меньше не пробовали?

Comment: Сейчас не думаю там хранить большие данные, думаю использовать это поле для того, что бы можно было добавить туда свободные даные, т.е. не привязанные к типам данных, для того что бы вывести их пользователю в качестве демонстрации, перед обработкой основных.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не знаю структуру файла, по этому я собираю каждую строчку в массив и хочу загрузщить её в базу, что бы показать пользователю, который выбирет от туда нужные колонки данных и язаного спрасю весь файл уже в нужные таблицы.

Comment: `file_dump` это название всего поля или конкретное поле в JSON-столбце? Если нужно, чтобы два JSON-значения красиво автоматически смержилось, не думаю, что это можно реализовать без кастомной обработки. Чтобы процессы не висли, можно попробовать запихнуть обработку в очередь (Jobs)

Comment: Насмотрелся про json в PostgreSQL , понял, что оптимальный вариант - это документ не более 2Кб , в остальных случаях сервер начинает этот массив разбивать на другие таблицы, делая это всё незаметно и вопрос скорости остаётся открытым. И по сути - да, что бы изменить этот массив, его нужно прочитать полностью или это делает сервер за вас, что по факту +- столько же времени. Конечно PostgreSQL пытается оптимизировать эти запросы, но тут много остаётся требований к самому документу. Лучший вариант - это бить документ на части и хранить его ID + JSONB. Тогда получим быстрый доступ к документу.